# Vis js ionicons nodes change color when selected

Tags: vis.js-network, vis.js, ionicons

I'm new in Vis.js and JavaScript but I'm willing to learn. I'm using nodes that change their color when they're hovered or selected. If I use shapes like 'dot' or 'square' it is ok, but I would like to get the same behaviour with icons like ionicons. The following code shows how I expected to get it work (using options settings). I'm planning to use `selectNode` and `hoverNode` events and updating the group (require creation of specific groups for selected or hovered nodes) but I think there is an easier way to accomplish it. Could you give me some advice? Here is my code:

```js
// create an array with nodes
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([{
    id: 1002,
    label: 'Juan',
    title: 'Juan Diaz Salizar',
    group: 'group_1'
  },
  {
    id: 1003,
    label: 'Martin',
    title: 'Sin datos',
    group: 'group_2'
  },
  {
    id: 1004,
    label: 'Pedro',
    title: 'Pedro Diaz Alcaraz',
    group: 'group_2'
  },
  {
    id: 1007,
    label: 'Vanessa',
    title: 'Juan Diaz Salizar',
    group: 'group_1'
  }
]);
// create an array with edges
var edges = new vis.DataSet([{
    from: 1003,
    to: 1002,
    label: 'tc 1',
    arrows: 'to'
  },
  {
    from: 1004,
    to: 1003,
    label: 'tc 2',
    arrows: 'to'
  },
  {
    from: 1007,
    to: 1003,
    label: 'tc 2',
    arrows: 'to'
  },
  {
    from: 1007,
    to: 1004,
    label: 'tc',
    arrows: 'to'
  }
]);

// create a network
var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
var data = {
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges
};

var options = {
  interaction: {
    hover: true
  },
  edges: {
    font: {
      size: 11,
      color: 'rgb(46,117,182)'
    },
    color: {
      color: 'rgb(189,215,238)',
      hover: 'rgb(46,117,182)'
    }
  },
  nodes: {
    size: 10
  },
  groups: {
    group_1: {
      shape: 'dot',
      color: {
        background: 'rgb(189,215,238)',
        border: 'rgb(46,117,182)',
        hover: {
          background: 'rgb(46,117,182)',
          border: 'rgb(46,117,182)'
        },
        highlight: {
          background: 'rgb(46,117,182)',
          border: 'rgb(46,117,182)'
        }
      },
      font: {
        size: 11,
        color: 'rgb(46,117,182)'
      }
    },
    group_2: {
      shape: 'icon',
      icon: {
        face: 'Ionicons',
        code: '\uf2d2',
        size: 20,
        color: {
          background: 'rgb(189,215,238)',
          border: 'rgb(46,117,182)',
          hover: {
            background: 'rgb(46,117,182)',
            border: 'rgb(46,117,182)'
          },
          highlight: {
            background: 'rgb(46,117,182)',
            border: 'rgb(46,117,182)'
          }
        }
      },
      font: {
        size: 11,
        color: 'rgb(46,117,182)'
      }
    }
  }
};

var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

```css
#mynetwork {
  width: 85%;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">

<div id="mynetwork"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you can see from [docs](http://visjs.org/docs/network/nodes.html), for `image` and `circularImage` shapes you can set `image.unselected` and `image.selected` options, although there's no `image.hover` or alike. There's also `chosen` option of nodes but according to docs, it can't contain anything that affects node images. So I think using events that you mentioned is a proper solution, somewhat straight-forward.

Comment: Thank you YakovL. I decided to use chose option for nodes in following way             nodes: {
                chosen : {
                    label: function(values, id, selected, hovering) {
                               values.color = 'red';
                               values.strokeColor = 'yellow';
                               values.strokeWidth = 3;
                    }
                }
            },

Comment: @WalterC right :) if it's helpful enough, consider accepting it (using the backtick button)